# OrderedDict too many values to unpack

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

My program is producing:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack.

I copied the lines of code that works in other instances.

```
new_dict = (("data", 0))
new_dict = collections.OrderedDict(new_dict) #the line producing the error
```

The only difference between this and the other ones that seem to work is that they have more values.

Comment: `(("data",0))` is equivalent to just `("data",0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new_dict = (("data", 0))
```

This is supposed to be a tuple containing key-value pairs. To create a tuple with just one element, add a trailing comma.

```
new_dict = (("data", 0),)
```